In python subplot get common ylabel for each column
Can someone help me to plot using matplotlib of having subplots as shown in below code. I need ylabel for each column and common xlabel. Is it possible to use twinx or make grids.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 2, sharex = True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
ax[0][0] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 1)
ax[1][0] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 3)
ax[2][0] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 5)
ax[3][0] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 7)
ax[0][1] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 2)
ax[1][1] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 4)
ax[2][1] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 6)
ax[3][1] = plt.subplot(4, 2, 8)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
ax9 = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
plt.tick_params(labelcolor='none', which='both', top=False, bottom=False, left=False, right=False)
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
ax9.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.07)
plt.show()

When I run this code I get this plot:

whereas I need this kind of plot:


You could use subfigures and set the supylabel for each separately, e.g.,
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

subfigs = fig.subfigures(1, 2)

axleft = subfigs[0].subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0))
axright = subfigs[1].subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0))

for ax in axright:
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

subfigs[0].supylabel("y label 1", x=-0.05)
subfigs[1].supylabel("y label 2", x=0.00)

fig.supxlabel("x label")


Note that you may have to play around with the image size or supylabel's x position argument to prevent overlapping with the tick labels.

worked with value of x=0.0 subfigs[0].supylabel("y label 1", x=0.00)

I want to include yticks for both y-axis left and right columns. Right now I can only see on left column. How can do that?

Just remove the for loop that I have
